# Listen to all event types of an EventDispatcher

Tags: apache-flex, flash, events

In Flex, is it possible to listen to all event types of an object that's an `IEventDispatcher`? `addEventListener`'s first parameter is the type, which is a string. In many cases the documentation is not clear what event type it fires. I'd like to attach a generic listener to inspect the events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to derive from this class and override the `dispatchEvent` method like this:

```
override public function dispatchEvent(event:Event):Boolean
{
    trace(event.type);
    return super.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, there isn't any built-in way of generically listening for all event types.  You would either have to develop a system for managing this or do something similar to what splash suggested.  Personally, I would create a custom event, override dispatchEvent, and dispatch your own custom event while passing the 'type' of the original event.

```
override public function dispatchEvent(event:Event):Boolean
{
    //Dispatch your custom event passing along with it the type of the original event.
    super.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.ALL, event.type);
    return super.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Then you could simply setup one listener for your custom event and easily track when and what events are firing.

Hope that helps.